# WebApi : How to have multiple translation at the same time

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I read a lot of post about localization in .net WebApi.
However, I want to generate a pdf file in 2 differents languages.

The workflow can be defined like this :
WebApplication -> WebApi -> MyController -> PdfService -> Generate pdf in fr AND en.

How can I implement that ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not clear what should happen with the two PDFs. Will they be stored somewhere or returned to the caller?

Comment: The two pdf are stored in a sub directories. They are generated sequentially. First in EN and second in FR. So the languages (culture) are always the sames. (EN & FR)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.